# BS button inside datalist input field?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input list="absolventini" id="search-absolvent-form-input" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
       </span>
      <datalist id="absolventini">
        <option value="1">
          <option value="2">
            <option value="3">
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="search-absolvent-form-input" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
       </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w1sfh52/1/) demo. Second input (text) has search icon inside input field. First input(datalist) icon is outside. I want that to be inside.

Comment: do you want a bootstrap only solution or CSS is also fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason behind this is the below style that is being applied to the button in the second form and not being applied to the button in the first form because if you see the below style applies to the last child of the form/ input-grp and  that having a `.btn` class but in you case the first form the `datalist` is the last child and not the button.

```
.input-group .form-control:last-child,
.input-group-addon:last-child,
.input-group-btn:first-child>.btn-group:not(:first-child)>.btn,
.input-group-btn:first-child>.btn:not(:first-child),
.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn,
.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group>.btn,
.input-group-btn:last-child>.dropdown-toggle {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

So the solution for this is to move the data list above the `span` tag and both the buttons will appear similar as if they are inside the input field. Below is the demo of the same. And here is the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w1sfh52/2/)**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input list="absolventini" id="search-absolvent-form-input" class="form-control">
      <datalist id="absolventini">
        <option value="1">
          <option value="2">
            <option value="3">
      </datalist>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
     </button>
     </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="search-absolvent-form-input" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
     </button>
     </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

One more solution would be to define a class like:

```
.input-btn-inside{
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

apply this to you button if in case you are not having them button as the last child of the `.input-group`

Hope it helps :)